# File assign to a desktop

Tags: spaces, mission-control

Can I make that a specific file opens in a specific space? (For instancem can I make that "receipt.pages" document always opens in space 2)

(I know that I can make an application open in a specific space: dock > ctrl click application > option > desktop 2. But *THIS IS NOT WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR*,  I ask if this is possible for a specific file not all files of an application)

Answer (score 1):

Was not able to find if a specific file could be opened in a specific space but you can make applications open there.

From https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18757?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US

**Assign apps to spaces**

If you assign an app to a particular space, it opens in that space by default.

Press and hold an app’s icon in the Dock. You may have to first open the app from Launchpad to see its icon in the Dock.

From the shortcut menu that appears, do one of the following:

Have the app open in the current space: Choose Options > This Desktop.

The app appears only in that space. However, if you open the app in full screen, it appears in its own space.

Have the app open in the current space on a specific display: Choose Options > Desktop on Display [number].

Have the app open in every space: Choose Options > All Desktops.

The app appears in every space.

Have the app open in whichever space you’re using at the time: Choose Options > None.

In Mission Control preferences, you can also specify that, when you switch to an app, your desktop should switch to a space with open windows for that app. To open Mission Control preferences, choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Mission Control.